# I have hands, but can't point

Tags: riddle

> I have hands, but can't point. I make a sound without a mouth, and I can measure 1 foot with what's on my face. What am I?

For you to answer this, you must know that it is you.

Comment: Is this an original riddle?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I wave my hands around](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/106536/5373)

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer! But in all honesty, as the discussion in the comments to my answer shows, it is not entirely clear in all details why the answer was correct. Would you mind enlightening us?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are a

> clock

because you have (obviously)

> clock hands and a clock face

you do make a sound without a mouth

> tick-tock

and you can measure a foot

> with twelve inches, which corresponds to the number of marks on your face!

Comment: I thought about this answer but there are a few things that make me doubt it. In particular, the hands do point, it doesn't really measure 1 foot and what about the last line "you must know that it is you"?

Comment: Yeah, I'm also not sure what to make of the last line. But the other points seem (admittedly given some level of abstraction) to allow for my interpretation above...

Comment: Don't the clock hands point to the numbers?

Comment: @DrD, There could be an argument that the hands lie on the lines on which the numbers reside.  But in normal speech/usage, I agree with you.

Comment: Maybe measuring a foot refers to the rhythm of poetry or music. Tick-Tock = 1 iamb.

Comment: @DrD indeed; teaching children how to tell the time on an analogue clock is based around "the little hand is pointing to X and the big hand is pointing at Y"

Answer (score 1):

For you to answer this, you must know that it is you.

> Not sure if I understand this part right, but are you a deck of cards?

I have hands, but can't point.

> sets of poker cards are called hands and there are "hand games" in Skat or Rommé.

I make a sound without a mouth,

> mixing the cards makes a specific sound, especially when done fast.

and I can measure 1 foot with what's on my face.

> typical playing card dimensions are 2.5x3.5 inches. As 2x(2.5+3,5) = 12 inches or 1 foot, you can measure one foot with these cards.

Comment: You could also say that the kings and queens are rulers, and as such you can measure with them?